# js function wont work

Tags: javascript, html, function

Got one easy question for you, but still hard for me...
All i'm trying to do, is maximize new, opened window with different button...But it doesn't work, cant figure out why .. can someone please tell me, what i do wrong?

```
<form>
    <input type="button" value="Create New Window" onclick="createWindow()" />
    <input type="button" value="Maximize New Window" onclick="maximizeWindow()" />
</form>

var maxWindow;
    function createWindow(){
        var winWidth = 300;
        var winHeight = 100;
        var winLeft = (screen.width - winWidth)/2;
        var winTop = (screen.height - winHeight)/2;
        var winOptions = ",width=" + winWidth + ",height=" + winHeight + ",left=" + winLeft + ",top=" + winTop;
        maxWindow = window.open("http://www.google.com","newWindow",winOptions);
        maxWindow.focus();
    }

    function maximizeWindow() {
        maxWindow.moveTo(0,0);
        maxWindow.resizeTo(screen.availWidth, screen.availHeight);
        maxWindow.focus();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
var maxWindow;
    function createWindow(){
        var winWidth = 300;
        var winHeight = 100;
        var winLeft = (screen.width - winWidth)/2;
        var winTop = (screen.height - winHeight)/2;
        var winOptions = ",width=" + winWidth + ",height=" + winHeight + ",left=" + winLeft + ",top=" + winTop+'fullscreen=yes';
        maxWindow = window.open("http://www.google.com","newWindow",winOptions);
        maxWindow.focus();
    }

    function maximizeWindow() {
        maxWindow.moveTo(0,0);
        maxWindow.resizeTo(screen.width, screen.height);
        maxWindow.focus();
    }
</script>
<form>
    <input type="button" value="Create New Window" onclick="createWindow()" />
    <input type="button" value="Maximize New Window" onclick="maximizeWindow()" />
</form>
```

i add this to first function 'fullscreen=yes' and in second function change second line with my code maxWindow.resizeTo(screen.width, screen.height);

Comment: please don't submit "spot the difference" answers.

Comment: i add this to first function 'fullscreen=yes' and in second function change second line with my code maxWindow.resizeTo(screen.width, screen.height);

Comment: so put that in your answer!

Comment: I believe the question is how to `maximize new, opened window with different button`. This code instantly maximizes the window on the first button click. I do not think that this will work for the OP.